# Hypercohomology of a direct image of a complex of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

$\newcommand{\hy}{\textrm{-}}$
Let $\mathcal{R}_X$ be a sheaf of rings on a smooth manifold $X$, let $\mathcal{R}_X\hy \mathsf{Mod}$ be the abelian category of $\mathcal{R}_X$-modules and let $D(X)=D(\mathcal{R}_X\hy \mathsf{Mod})$ be its derived category.

Assume that  $\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ is a complex of $\mathcal{R}_X$-modules on $X$ and let $f: X\to Y$ be a continuous map.

Clearly, $f_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ is a complex of $\mathcal{R}_Y$-modules but it is not an element of the derived category $D(Y)$ yet. As far as I understand, the total derived functor $Rf_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ is the embedding of $f_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ in $D(Y)$.

In light of the above, I would like to know if it makes sense to talk about the hypercohomology $\mathbb H^{\bullet}(Y, f_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet})$ of $f_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ at all because I have never seen such an object defined in the literature. In the literature, I have only seen $\mathbb H^{\bullet}(Y, Rf_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet})$. This is very confusing because on the other hand, for an $\mathcal{R}_X$-module $\mathcal{M}$, I have seen in the literature the sheaf cohomology $H^{\bullet}(Y, f_*M)$ defined. Can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: What is the derived category for you? Every definition of derived category I’ve seen has as objects complexes of modules.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The problem is that I am not sure if we are allowed to view $f_*\mathcal{C}$ directly as an element of the derived category because the functor $f_*$, which acts on $\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ is not derived. I am confused and the literature is not clear at all. I think that a complex $\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$ of modules belongs to the derived category provided that it has not been acted upon by a functor $F$. In case a functor $F$ has acted, we have to take the total derived functor $RF$ of the complex $RF(\mathcal{C}^{\bullet})$.  But that is why I turned to the experts to explain.

Comment: My understanding is that it is fine to take hypercohomology of $f_* C^\bullet$, but you cannot expect it to be a nice object, because $f_*$ is not exact -- pushing forward gives rise to phantom cohomology terms that wasn't there before. The hypercohomology of $Rf_* C^\bullet$ on the other hand is a well-behaved thing, for example by the Grothendieck spectral sequence $R\Gamma_Y \circ Rf_* C^\bullet \cong R\Gamma_X C^\bullet$ so it is the hypercohomology of $C^\bullet$ itself. I am no expert though.

Comment: @Balarka Sen Thank you. In my opinion, your comment counts as a legitimate  answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

The functor $f_*$ does extend to a functor between categories of chain complexes and so it makes perfect sense to talk about the cohomology of $f_*\mathcal{C}^{\cdot}$.

Be careful though, while we can view the *object* $f_*\mathcal{C}^{\cdot}$ as an element of the derived category (just apply the functor from chain complexes to the derived category), the functor $f_*$ itself is in general only left exact and therefore does not descend to a functor between derived categories. Typically people want constructions that are functorial, hence the emphasis on derived functors.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. What happens in the case when the direct image functor $f_*$ of the continuous map $f:S\to Y$ is exact (say when $f$ is a closed embedding, for instance). Then, I would say we have $Rf_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}=f_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet}$. Is that right? Therefore, the hypercohomology can be computed by the fact that $\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(Y, f_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet})=\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(Y, Rf_*\mathcal{C}^{\bullet})=\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(R\Gamma(X, \mathcal{C}^{\bullet})=\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(X, \mathcal{C}^{\bullet})$. In particular, this holds true for any exact functor $F$?

Comment: That’s correct (except I’m unsure of the meaning of your last sentence). In practice, we compute derived functors by choosing an “adapted class” of objects and then apply the usual functor on chain complexes. More precisely, we pick out a subcategory of chain complexes whose homotopy category is equivalent to the (bounded) derived category and on which the functor is exact. A common choice for left exact functors is the category of complexes of injective objects (provided enough of these exist)

Comment: Let me first address two errors in my last comment: $1)$ I meant $f:X\to Y$, not  $f: S\to Y$. $2)$ It is $\mathbb{H}^{\bullet}(R\Gamma(X, \mathcal{C}^{\bullet}))$. In the last sentence, I meant that we have $RF=F$ in the derived category for any exact functor $F$. This is correct, as far as I understand implicitly from books? Do you agree?

Comment: @FlaviusAetius That’s essentially correct. Although to be precise, the correct statement is that if $F$ is an exact functor between abelian categories, then the functor induced by $F$ on the category of chain complexes descends to a functor on the level of derived categories